# A Question about Abelian Dualities in 2+1 Dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, duality

I have a question from the paper

[More Abelian Dualities in 2+1 Dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04012).

On  page 3, it says that we flow towards IR by sending $\alpha\rightarrow\infty$ and tuning the mass to zero.

$$S[\phi ;A]=\int d^{3}x |(\partial_{\mu}-iA_{\mu})\phi|^{2}-\alpha|\phi|^{4}.$$

My question is that why this limit takes the theory to IR.